# How can I improve my collision detection in my simple Javascript game

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

I have completed a tutorial on how to create a simple brick breaker game in Javascript and now would like to expand on it. I have run into an issue of how to differentiate between a side/side collision and a top/bottom collision.

Right now, the collision detection function I have only checks if there has been a collision. Then in a separate class, if the collision function returns true, it negates the y coordinate of the trajectory, but not the x. So when the ball collides with either the top or bottom of a brick, it will change y directions which works, but if it collides with the side of a brick, it keeps traveling in the same x direction.

Here's the collision function:

```
export function objectCollision(ball, gameObject){
  //Position of Ball
  let topOfBall = ball.position.y;
  let bottomOfBall = ball.position.y + ball.height;
  let leftSideOfBall = ball.position.x;
  let rightSideOfBall = ball.position.x + ball.width;

  //Position of Object
  let topOfObject = gameObject.position.y;
  let bottomofObject = gameObject.position.y + gameObject.height;
  let leftSideOfObject = gameObject.position.x;
  let rightSideOfObject = gameObject.position.x + gameObject.width;

  //Split up the top/bottom and left/right hit detection (causes abnormal behavior)
  //Need to negate the x trajectory
  //Set ball.speed.x = -ball.speed.x if left/right hit detection

  if(bottomOfBall >= topOfObject && topOfBall <= bottomofObject && leftSideOfBall >= leftSideOfObject && rightSideOfBall <= rightSideOfObject){
    //ball.speed.x = -ball.speed.x;
      return true;
    }
  else
    return false;
}
```

Then in the brick class, we change the y coordinate of the trajectory.

```
//Brick class
import { objectCollision } from "/src/collisionDetection"

export default class Brick{
  //......

  update(deltaTime){
    if(objectCollision(this.game.ball, this)){
      this.game.ball.speed.y = -this.game.ball.speed.y;
      this.isHit = true;
    }
  }

  //.....
}
```

My issue is that if I check for y coordinate collisions separate from the x coordinate collisions, it will detect a collision when the ball's x coordinate is the same as a brick's, even if the ball is lower/higher than the brick. I've tried checking for y's first and then in a nested if() check the x's, but it yielded the same result.

Something along the lines of:

```
if(bottomOfBall >= topOfObject && topOfBall <= bottomofObject && leftSideOfBall){
  if(leftSideOfBall >= leftSideOfObject && rightSideOfBall <= rightSideOfObject){
    ball.speed.x = -ball.speed.x;
    return true;
  }
}
```

But it gave the same abnormal behavior or broke collision all together.

Hopefully it's something simple that I'm just not seeing and an extra pair of eyes would fix. I really don't want to completely redo the collision detection.

Comment: Just thinking out loud here, but could you compute which edge of the brick is nearest the ball and then see if the distance from the center of the ball to that edge is less than or equal to the ball's radius?

Comment: can I assume that the ball is circle, and its width and height equals?

Comment: The ball (well, pretty much everything) is an image with an id, so it's technically a square. It doesn't have a radius but a width and height. Think of it like a sprite in a video game where the starting position is at the top left corner of the image. So "ball.position.x" and "ball.position.y" would be the top left corner, "ball.position.x + ball.width" would be the top right corner, and "ball.position.y + ball.height" would be the bottom left corner. But yes, the width and height are equal.

Comment: I'm afraid computing the nearest edge could be too expensive. It would also require a LOT of refactoring and I was hoping to avoid that.